# flutter phone verification with firebase the sms message doesn't appear

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have set everything correctly to make the phone verification work with the firebase, but the message never shows up on my phone.

The small app I use to test this function has two screens: one with a button to send the message, and another one to verifier the code that has been sent.

i used in it this packages:

```
  firebase_auth: ^3.6.2
  firebase_core: ^1.20.0
  pinput: ^2.2.7
```

here is the code

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pinput/pinput.dart';
import 'package:test_sms_auth/firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _verificationCode = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("test for login via sms :"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await sendNotification('+++RealPohneNumber+++');
                },
                child: const Text('demande the code to log in :')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> sendNotification(String mobileNo) async {
    final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    int forceResendToken = 0;

    await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: mobileNo,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
      verificationCompleted: (authCredential) =>
          phoneVerificationCompleted(authCredential),
      verificationFailed: (authException) =>
          phoneVerificationFailed(authException),
      codeSent: (verificationId, [code]) =>
          phoneCodeSent(verificationId, [code!]),
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: phoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
      forceResendingToken: forceResendToken,
    );
  }

  phoneVerificationCompleted(AuthCredential authCredential) {
    print('verified');
  }

  phoneVerificationFailed(FirebaseException authException) {
    print('failed');
    print('Message: ${authException.message}');
    print('Code: ${authException.code}');
  }

  phoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout(String verificationCode) {
    this._verificationCode = verificationCode;
  }

  phoneCodeSent(String verificationCode, List<int> code) async {
    print('code : $code');
    print('verificationCode : $_verificationCode');
    this._verificationCode = verificationCode;
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PageToEnterPinCode(
          verificationCode: verificationCode,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageToEnterPinCode extends StatelessWidget {
  PageToEnterPinCode({Key? key, this.verificationCode}) : super(key: key);
  final verificationCode;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 40),
          const Text('enter validation code '),
          const SizedBox(height: 40),
          Pinput(
            defaultPinTheme: defaultPinTheme,
            pinputAutovalidateMode: PinputAutovalidateMode.onSubmit,
            length: 8,
            showCursor: true,
            onCompleted: (pin) {
              print(pin);
              signInWithSmsCode(pin);
            },
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }

  final defaultPinTheme = PinTheme(
    width: 56,
    height: 56,
    textStyle: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        color: Color.fromRGBO(30, 60, 87, 1),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromRGBO(234, 239, 243, 1)),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
  );

  Future<User?> signInWithSmsCode(String smsCode) async {
    try {
      final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

      AuthCredential authCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
          verificationId: verificationCode, smsCode: smsCode);
      UserCredential authResult =
          await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
      if (authResult.user != null) {
        print('');
        print('PHONE AUTH UID :: ' + authResult.user!.uid);
        print('PHONE AUTH CREDENTIALS :: ' + authCredential.toString());
        print('');
        return authResult.user;
      } else {
        print('the code din\'t match ');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

even in the debug it shows me that the message has been sent but nothing arrive in the phone